# Azure Table Sharing Partition Key Across Tables

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm hoping to keep common data from the same user partitioned together. Normally I'd just use the same partition key to accomplish that but in this case the data is in different tables.  E.g users, photos, friends, etc

I have seen it explicitly stated but I assume that even if I use the partition key across tables that I won't be able to accomplish this. Can anyone validate or disprove?

Comment: What are we validating or disproving? Can you clarify what you're trying to get by partitioning the data this way and then we can help you figure out how to achieve what you want?

Comment: The value in using a common partitioning key is the data is served from the same server.  I'm curious if that is true across tables or just within a table.

Comment: Okay, that is totally answerable. :) I'll post something, if you want to update your question that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data with the same partition key but in different tables has no guarantee of being on the same server. If you check out the [Storage Table Design Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/), particularly the section titled 'Table Partitions', you'll find 'The account name, table name and PartitionKey together identify the partition within the storage service where the table service stores the entity.' That guide may help you clarify this question and anything related.